# Множественное наследование с++

Tags: c++, множественное-наследование

Прошу вашей помощи в объяснении множественного наследования. Возникают проблемы с наследованием методов. Вот пример есть метод `fill();` который заполняет поля объекта ). В классе `Транспорт` он заполняет общие поля ,  и что бы не дублировать код в классах наследниках я вызываю этот метод в методе `fill();` Класса `сухопутный транспорт` и `водный транспорт`. Но получаетcя если я буду реализовывать класс `Амфибии` мне нужно будет вызвать метод `fill();` из классов  `сухопутный транспорт` и `водный транспорт`. Что приведёт к вызову метода `fill();`  класса `Транспорт`  дважды.  Скорее всего я делаю всё не так как нужно, поэтому нуждаюсь в толковом объяснении что да как делать. Все были когда-то новичками, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

class Transport {

public:
    float weight;
    float loadСapacity; // грузоподьёмность
    string color;


    virtual void fill() {
        cout << "Enter weight: "  << endl;
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter color: " << endl;
        cin >> color;
        cout << "Enter load capacity: " << endl;
        cin >> loadСapacity;
    }
    void beep() {
        cout << "Beeep-beeep";
    }

public:
};

class LandTransport : public virtual Transport {   //назевемный транспорт
protected:
    void fillOnlyLand(){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter number Of Wheels: ";
        cin >> numberOfWheels;
        cout << "Enter land speed: ";
    }
    int numberOfWheels,landSpeed; // колличество колёс, cкорость на суше

     void fill()override{
        Transport::fill();
        fillOnlyLand();
    }


    void drive() {
        cout << "Brrrrr I'm going by land....... "<<endl;
    }

};

class WaterTransport:public virtual  Transport{  // Водный транспорт
public:
    float displacement,waterSpeed; // водоизмещение,скорость на воде
   void fill()override{

       Transport::fill();

       cout << "Enter displacement: ";
            cin >> displacement;
       cout << "Enter water Speed ";
       cin >>waterSpeed;
   }
    void swimming() {
        cout << "Yuhhu I'm swimming"<<endl;
    }

};

class Amphibian:public LandTransport, public WaterTransport{  //  машины-амфибии

    void fill()override{

    }
};



int main() {


    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как это обычно бывает в подобных случаях, необходимость наследования, тем более виртуального, тут сомнительна. Вам следовало бы привести сценарии использования этих классов.

Comment: Мне просто нужно было придумать задачу на множественное наследование и с использованием виртуального класса , больше в голову ничего не пришло, думаю примут :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно у вас в коде уже есть намёк на решение. Нужно иметь в промежуточных классах функцию заполнения только специфической информации (без базовой части `Transport`). Например, я вижу функцию `fillOnlyLand()` для `LandTransport`. Аналогичную надо завести и для `WaterTransport`. А в классе амфибии для функции `fill` вызывать следующую цепочку:

```
Transport::fill();
LandTransport::fillOnlyLand();
WaterTransport::fillOnlyWater();
```